# Read database GeoIPASNum.dat with PHP

Tags: php

How can I got informations from GeoIPASNum.dat with PHP? There is no buildin function probably.

Comment: do you have the documentation of the format for the "GeoIPASNum.dat" file?

Comment: http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/asnum/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz - I have only this

Comment: did you have a look at http://www.maxmind.com/app/php ?